# Dart POST JSON to Google App Engine via EndPoints

Tags: json, google-app-engine, dart

Does anyone know why I keep getting Error 400 Parse Error when POST to App Engine? My JSON is fine. I have JSON.encoded it. Anyone run into these issues before???

This is my HTTPRequest code.

```dart
sendData = JSON.encode(data);

_httpRequest = new HttpRequest()
        ..open(method, url)
        ..setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenKey)
        ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => _loadEnd(_httpRequest))
        ..send(sendData);
```

Comment: Have you checked the comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261862/this-api-does-not-support-parsing-form-encoded-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to specify the headers as Content-type: application/json as without it the data is text/html. Silly mistake.

Updated POST here:

`sendData = JSON.encode(data);`

_httpRequest = new HttpRequest()
        ..open(method, url)
        ..setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenKey)
        ..setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        ..onLoadEnd.listen((e) => _loadEnd(_httpRequest))
        ..overrideMimeType("application/json")
        ..send(sendData);